# Convert back pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, stanford-nlp, dataloader

I'm doing a research on sentiment analysis on twitter using lstm and glove. I use the pytorch dataloader to do train, validation and test splits.

The split data has gone through preprocessing stages such as case folding, filtering, stemming, stopwords removal, and tokenization.

But I am confused to change the dataloader back to the original tweet form. So is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you share some working code and what exactly you would like to do? What is the original tweet that you are referring to?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.